# How can I capture an OpenBSD install console?

Tags: console, openbsd

So.. **How can I save the text that is based on Q/A's when installing an OpenBSD 5.3?** Or I only have the choice to manually type the texts down? or an OCR software using printscreens?

Answer (score 5):

One often-overlooked easy way is to do the install over a serial port.  That assumes the machine has a serial port, which is not always the case.

I know, you will say "but my machine doesn't do a serial port console".  That doesn't matter.  There are two ways to tell OpenBSD to use a serial console, the first, most useful in doing a fresh install from a CD is to use the boot loader:

```
>> OpenBSD/amd64 BOOT 3.23
boot> stty com0 9600

com0: 9600 baud
boot> set tty com0
switching console to com0
>> OpenBSD/amd64 BOOT 3.23
boot> boot
```

The second is to put these same parameters in `/etc/boot.conf`.

```
# cat /etc/boot.conf
stty com0 9600
set tty com0
```

Then you can just log your terminal to a file, or cut and paste from putty, etc.  I have some machines that "don't do serial consoles" booting this way, and unless there is a boot failure on the BIOS level, it works great.

If you are using `tip`, you can start recording a session by setting the variable `script`.  You set a variable in tip by issuing `~` `s`.

```
kellogg# tip tty03
connected
~[set] script
```

The default file name is `tip.record`.  You can change that name by setting the `record` variable.  The default recording includes non-printable characters, you can stop `tip` from doing that by setting the `beautify` variable.

You can also create a `.tiprc` file in your home directory to set these variables for you on any tip session.

```
set script
set beautify
set record=/tmp/tip.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can I redirect the output to a file? ex.: flashdrive?

Comment: @gaskopeter I've added how to make `tip` record your session, after figuring out how to do that.

Comment: Or you can use `tip` (whatever) inside `tmux` and use tmux's 'pipe-pane' command. Or `script $outfile` ... Many options to save text output.

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha Also an excellent method.  OP asked for a concrete example so I chose this one.