# Available console solution for a physical machine running OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, serial-console, remote-management, remote-control

If we have a physical server running OpenBSD, what are the available remote console solutions for it? Are there any unique methods because it's an OpenBSD?

Console of course means if there is no network connection for the machine via ex.: SSH.

Comment: What physical server does it run on, maybe it already offers something like KVM / IPMI serial over lan or similar. Otherwise, you did already look into the classic serial console as e.g. explained in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96916/how-can-i-capture-an-openbsd-install-console ? For serial console also see http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq7.html section - **7.6 - How do I use a serial console?** or also http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/openbsd-connect-serial-console/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of the following alternatives:

- making the serial port available using a network attached serial console switch
- connect keyboard, video and mouse to a network attached KVM switch
- connect the serial port to another host and make the serial port
  network connected with `socat`

Comment: When I've used FreeBSD and had to do kernel debugging I had to use a serial console. I can't speak for OpenBSD, but I do know that I also could have done this over firewire.

Comment: IPMI is also supported (which doesn't necessarily mean using it is a good idea security-wise).